# Apache SSL module preventing httpd from starting?

Tags: ssl, https, apache2.2

I have a couple of sites hosted under simple http protocol. I need to put https in one of theses, but when I try to enable ssl:

```
# a2enmod ssl
```

All my http hosted websites just stop working. With no additional configuration, only by disabling the module everything start to work again.

With the module enabled, when I try:

```
# apache2ctl restart
```

I get: `httpd not running, trying to start`

You guys have any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked Apache's errolog for any error messages?

Comment: Off-topic here, voting to move to ServerFault.

Comment: Have you checked Apache's *SSL* log for error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Check your configuration for sections within `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` or `<IfModule ssl_module>`: there's almost certainly a configuration mistake within these sections.

Comment: So, I did a `grep -r "<IfModule mod_ssl.c"`, and here it is all theses sections: http://pastebin.com/PKYUMLP6 Everything seems ok.